# Raw Socket receives 1504 bytes (MTU = 1500)

Tags: c++, linux, raw-sockets, mtu

In my application I open a raw socket (LINUX kernel 3.8.5) with the following
instruction:

```
::socket( PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons((uint16_t)ETH_P_ALL));
```

all is working fine, I'm able to receive it and send it to another interface.
However some time the

```
::recvfrom()
```

on that sockets returns 1518 (1504 payload bytes + 14 ETH_HLEN).

When I try to send this buffer of 1518 bytes however the instruction

```
::send(......)
```

returns EMSGSIZE( Message too long).

Note that on my NIC interface the MTU is 1500 so I would have expected a maximum
of 1514 (payload + ETH_HLEN) bytes retrieved with the ::recvfrom

The ethtype is 0x0800 so it's not a vlan tagged frame hence those 4 bytes "extra" are not due to a vlan tag

Do you have an explanation for it ?

Comment: have you enabled `gro` or `tso` or similar option in your nic ? if the nic is doing some segmentation offload, it may report packet up to 64k size regardless of mtu

Answer (score 1):

More on the matter, atm to debug the problem I have this configuration:

eth0(Server1)-------------->eth0(Server2)-----NAT----->dummy0(Server2)

between Server1 and Server2 there is no switch, nothing, just a cable,
and dummy0 is a NIC obtained with the dummy network module.

Sniffing on eth0(Server1) "TX side" and on eth0(Server2) "RX side" this is what
I'm getting:

TX side:

```
1514 bytes, sequence number  15476 
1514 bytes, sequence number  15477 
1514 bytes, sequence number  15478 
1514 bytes, sequence number  15479
```

On the RX side I'd expect the same but I get:

```
1514 bytes, sequence number 15476
1518 bytes, sequence number 15477
1514 bytes, sequence number 15479
```

funny thing is that while the 15478 was not received the last 4 bytes
in those 1518 bytes (seq number 15477) are the first 4 bytes in the payload
of the lost eth packet.

SOLVED: It was the GRO option, indeed thanks to that option on the ::rcv was able
        to get 2 or more ethernet frames at once, this why for example a sequence
        number "appeared" missing (it was in reality merged with a previous one),
        the fact that for some packet I got 1518 was due size of the buffer passed
        at the ::rcv, passing a much larger buffer indeed I do not loose any content.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the MTU is specific to the connection, because it depends on the entire path from source to destination - not just your local interface. If you are sending to a different address than the one you deceived the packet from, it seems quite plausible that the MTUs might be different.

Quoting from the [Linux man pages](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man7/ip.7.php):

> When PMTU discovery is enabled the kernel automatically keeps track of the path MTU per destination host. When it is connected to a specific peer with connect(2) the currently known path MTU can be retrieved conveniently using the IP_MTU socket option (e.g. after a EMSGSIZE error occurred). It may change over time. For connectionless sockets with many destinations the new also MTU for a given destination can also be accessed using the error queue (see IP_RECVERR). A new error will be queued for every incoming MTU update.

Comment: Disabling it just means the kernel won't keep track of it. That's not going to change the size of the path MTU - it just stops you from being able to find out what it is.

Comment: well I would like or to receive at maximum 1514 bytes or at least being able to send more than 1514.

Comment: Have you tried setting your MTU to something much lower - say 1000? If your MTU is always the smallest on both paths, then in theory it should be the same for both sending and receiving. If that still doesn't work, then I guess the problem must be something else.

Comment: Setting an MTU of 1400 I see packets sent with maximum size of 1414 but they arrive (at least retrieve from the raw socket) with sizes of 1518

Comment: Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.